# Не работает функция console.log

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

Нативная функция `console.log` ничего не выводит в **firebug** окне. При этом функция `alert` работает как должна. При подробном выводе получаю следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тестировалось на вот таком коде:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
console.log("tst");
alert("!");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS

Это происходит на **любой** кодировке.

версия ff:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

версия firebug:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: допишите версию браузера, попробуйте задать другую кодировку

Comment: @user2455111 дополнил вопрос

Comment: проверил у себя, такая же версия, полет нормальный

Comment: @Sergey добавил версию firebug , сравните со своей

Comment: @perfect Проверил, полет нормальный. Правда у меня firebug menu немного по другому выглядит.

Comment: Допишите в html кодировку: <meta charset="utf-8"/> и отвыкайте пользоваться фаербагом, он больше не развивается.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму смена кодировки не помогла. сброс настроек firebug не помог. что сейчас в FF используется для отладки вместо firebug?

Comment: @perfect, встроенный отладчик, кстати команда фаербага свалила допиливать его если я правильно помню. Он не менее функционален, но ряда мелких красивостей которые мне когда-то нравились в фаербаге там нету

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму как вызвать встроенный отладчик?

Comment: btw я совсем не уверен что ошибка возникает именно благодаря фаербагу, это замечание между делом было

Comment: @perfect, да f12 так же как везде, только фаербаг выключить надо сначала, можно ctrl+shift+i, можно меню-developer

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму спасибо, в нативном отладчике все хорошо.

Comment: Добавление meta charset лично у меня делает все хорошо не только в нативном отладчике, я даже сейчас проверил специально

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку [Firebug в современных версиях Firefox больше не существует](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/saying-goodbye-to-firebug/), а в нативном отладчике все хорошо, полагаю вопрос больше неактуален.